# The origin of awesomesauce and weak sauce

Tags: etymology, orthography, compounds

> John's ***awesomesauce*** weekend in Vegas ended prematurely.
>
> And he prayed with such authority that my prayers felt like ***weak sauce*** by comparison.

How did the words *awesomesauce* and *weak sauce* originate and when were they used for the first time?

Also, is it correct for there to be a space between *weak sauce* but for there to be no space in *awesomesauce*?

Comment: I wrote an answer but this has been closed. Both are in the OED, but only "weak sauce" has made Merriam-Webster. Nobody knows the origin of either, but weak sauce is attested in 1989 in the San Jose Mercury News, and awesomesauce on Usenet in 2001. Origin of "weak sauce" as a term for something bad/disappointing should be obvious. There's also a Grammarly post on the topic which I won't link because it's totally wrong based on the OED's evidence.

Comment: [Reader's Digest:](https://www.rd.com/list/buzzword-origins/) This slang term for “good” was first uttered by the character Strong Bad in the Homestar Runner web series of animated shorts, created by brothers Mike and Matt Chapman in the early 2000s.

Comment: @StuartF: Sorry about that! It's happened to me several times, so I know it can be very irritating. I've sometimes cut & pasted the text from my "thwarted Answer" into a temporary file, and voted to reopen (if others endorse the reopen, my saved text is ready and waiting). BTW - I assume ***weak** sauce* is modeled after figurative *and* literal ***strong / weak beer*** (there's also figurative ***strong meat***, but no-one refers to ***weak meat*** so far as I know).

Comment: @StuartF You should be able to post your answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both expressions appears to have originated at the beginning of the 21c according to Green’s Dictionary of Slang:

***weaksauce (n.)***

> (US teen/campus) something or someone second-rate, tedious, specifically an unfunny joke.
>
> - 2002    [US]    Teen Lingo: The Source for Youth Ministry  weaksauce n. Joke that didn’t quite make you laugh ‘That was weaksauce.’.
> - 2014    [US]    Eble UNC-CH Campus Sl. Spring 2014 16: WEAK SAUCE — something mediocre, boring: X: ‘I think I’ll just stay in tonight.’ Y: ‘Weak sauce, man!’.

***awesomesauce (adj.)***

> (US) epitomizing excellence; also as excl. of approbation [underpinned by brand name of cleaning product Awesome Sauce].
>
> - 2001        alt.tv.kids-in-hall 22 Sept. [Usenet group]  You guys are awesomesauce.
> - 2005        Urban Dict. 8 June  awesome sauce a beautifully assonant phrase which can and should be used on any occasion where joy and elation are expressed.
> - 2016    [US]    C. Eble UNC-CH Campus Sl. Spring 2016 1: AWESOMESAUCE - excellent: X: ‘I’ll have this project done by tomorrow.’ Y: ‘Awesomesauce.’.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters note, the precise etymology remains unknown, but it seems reasonable to suspect that these come from the slang term "the sauce," meaning alcohol (see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20sauce)).

Incidentally, I've always thought of "the sauce" as slang from the UK or Australia, but I haven't found any sources to back that claim up; regardless, it seems less common in contemporary American slang.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the expression "weak sauce," I note the following (unmoored) instance from an [untitled column](https://spectatorarchive.library.columbia.edu/cgi-bin/columbia?a=d&d=cs19951207-01.2.12.1&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22weak+sauce%22------) in the *Columbia [University (in New York City)] Spectator* (December 7, 1995):

> Special shout outs to: ... Peter "can't she buy a bigger shirt?" Freeman, Zach "that's **weak sauce**" Rothenberg, Jason "you plagiarized my stories all semester, you greedy bastard" Shames, Jessica "was that e-mail I heard?" Bloch, Dayna "I'm never gonna be in Playboy—l can't even wink!" Alpine, the rest of 119th Managing Board, the anonymous Emily, C. Lowell Harriss, and the innumerable nagging Drectacle and non-editorial bastards who have literally begged and pleaded to be in the non-nitebox (i.e. Bianca "purple revolution" Strul, who will always be the sweetest-smelling person alive.) Shireen- Keep your P-funks alight and your spirits high. You're the best. Please keep in touch because I'll miss you very much. Love, ELS

This occurrence matches the "teen/campus" milieu that Jonathon Green (cited in Gio's answer) identifies as the source of the expression—but is somewhat older than the start of the twenty-first century.

A much early but surely unrelated instance of a similar idea appears in F. Dixon, "[Sunday Excursions](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/61291552?searchTerm=%22weak+sauce%22)," in the *[Grafton, New South Wales] Clarence and Richmond Examiner* (December 31, 1901):

> Holidays are so numerous now-a-days that Sunday desecration is without excuse. As a rule, these excursions are not patronized by the "weary workers" who have no week-day opportunities of gaining "a few hours of pure ozone," but by a class of persons who are "gone" on selfish pleasure, end care little for church worship and God. It adds very **weak "sauce"** to my friend's arguments, to call me a "faddist," but reminds one of the saying, "When you've a *bad* case, abuse the plaintiff. We hope, however, to survive this shock.

I have not found any pre-2000 instances of "awesomesauce" or "awesome sauce."